# Trying to find cookies for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I am trying to find the folder for cookies from Chrome to copy them off of an old hard drive, and transfer them to a new one.

However, when I get to the appdata/local/google/chrome/userdata, there is no "default" folder, which apparently where the cookies are stored.

Since the folder isn't there, are the cookies simply lost?

Thank You

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/186609/how-do-i-transfer-copy-cookies-from-one-browser-to-another-or-same-browser-fro

Answer (score 0):

Should be in C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

Are you sure it definitely isn't there? Are you looking in the correct user folder? The cookies themselves is a SQLite file.

Comment: The folder genuinely is not there. Interestingly enough, I found a file titled "cookies" in a folder "Profile 2". This cookies file is not a SQLite file though. I've decided to just copy and paste the entire Chrome folder to the other computer, instead of just finding the specific file. If it's there, that should get it.